# Как прижать iframe к краю страницы?

Tags: css3, html, html5, css

Вставил код с youTube к себе на сайт. Вот этот код

```
<iframe width="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLE13CEEBC74F0632A&amp;hl=ru_RU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

А прижать к краю видео не могу, вот  сайт - http://musirkstrim.ru/. Обратите внимание на видео, рамка вокруг него это iframe, мне нужно, чтоб видео было полностью прижато к левому краю, как это сделать?

Comment: Рома Прогер, Миха Николаев...

`facepalm.jpg`

Comment: Оффтоп конечно, но сайт читаеться как МУРЗИКстрим.РУ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обворачиваешь в DIV потом позиционируешь его как Вашей душе угодно.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.video {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <iframe width="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLE13CEEBC74F0632A&amp;hl=ru_RU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```